# How to close a pop-up window that don't want to be closed?

Tags: kill

I am using a Ansys Fluent software and a small pop-up window "Messages" pops up in front of my main window "Meshing" ([a print screen of the image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utATc.png)). I can't close the pop-up window by clicking on its Close tab button to be able to access to the main window which is behind this pop-up window "Messages".

Kill job will close both widows.

```
:~$ top

top - 00:56:20 up  1:11,  1 user,  load average: 0.32, 0.28, 0.31
Tasks: 231 total,   1 running, 230 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.9 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3923928 total,   184304 free,  2033444 used,  1706180 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4071420 total,  4071420 free,        0 used.  1298032 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                        
 1113 root      20   0  447200  97520  77876 S   1.3  2.5   2:39.56 Xorg                           
 2532 ubuntu    20   0 2421736 523812 105676 S   1.3 13.3   7:30.97 Web Content                    
 5295 root      20   0 4004180 543832 134808 S   1.3 13.9   0:26.03 mono                           
 5391 root      20   0 2947308 398608 230632 S   1.0 10.2   0:13.50 ansyswbu.exe
```

This command below will terminate both widows.

```
sudo kill -9 5391
```

Comment: Why are you running it as `root`?

Comment: I am new to Linux. I was just trying things. ANSYS was install as root. If I don't us root to start it, things are not working properly. I don't know if it related to the VPN or the license.  However, I don't want to kill the job, I just want to close the small "Messages" window.

Comment: use xkill command

Answer (score 3):

Find the window id with:

```
$ wmctrl -mlpx
```

Explanation:

```
-l     List the windows being managed by the window manager.
       One line is output for each window, with the line broken up into 
       space separated columns. The first column always contains 
       the window entity as a hexadecimal integer.
```

Then, terminate the window with:

```
$ wmctrl -ic <window id>
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I got stuck with "Open file" which seems to have same window ID as other chrome window - I was able to find it like this, but not to close it.

Comment: Any way to help identify the correct window? Any chance I can just click it? Also will this method works when `sudo xkill` doesn't manage to kill the pop-up? I have already tried that.